# Dynamically creating preg pattern?

Tags: php, html, parsing, preg-match, bbcode

**Hello.**

I want to try and make a BBCode parser, and as far as I know, preg functions are the most convenient to find and replace bbcode with html.

In the past I have used a lot of str_replace over and over, which isn't very efficient.

I want to create a BBCode and store it in the DB, so given the BBCode structure:

```
[image]{URL}[/image]
```

and the HTML: `<img src="{URL}" alt="" .. />`

How can I use PHP to compare these two inputs and find the necessary preg pattern to use when parsing the BBcode in content?

What I want to achieve is the DB also storing this pattern, and when it is time to parse a large text for bbcodes, it will know exactly how to do it. No hardcoding.

*I searched a bit to try and find relevant topics on this, but I could only find exact patterns on how to resolve url bbcode etc, so pardon me if this really does exist somewhere.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the regexp and replacement patterns in the DB:

```
regExp: \[image\](.*?)\[/image\]
replacement: <img src="$1"/>
```

Then later retrieve these from the database and call `preg_replace()` with them as arguments. Note that you should be able to do it with a single call, since you can specify the regexp and replacement as arrays, and it will perform all of them at once.

Comment: **Thank you very much**. I've taken this and worked with it as my base. I got stuff working now. The only problem I have is if I have several variables in the bbcode, like {URL} and {TEXT}, replacing them with $1 and $2, they sometimes come in the wrong order when parsed.
But I guess it's an easy fix once I focus on it. :)

Comment: You might want to look for a more powerful template system.